# Particle Hair Not Rendering in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I'm making a character in Blender based off of Darrin Lile's character modeling series. However, instead of making an object for hair like he did, I decided to try using particle hair. However, when I try to render my hair, it does not show up. Can anyone help tell me what to fix? I'll include the blend file below.

[image]

Comment: Are you in edit mode with the hair object selected? I think there is a bug affecting that.

Comment: Nope, I am in object mode and I have nothing selected, but when I attempt to render, it just does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the convert button?  That is the answer I keep seeing, [Convert Cycles Hair Particle System to Mesh Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/convert-cycles-hair-particle-system-to-mesh-object). Hope this helps I am new to blender so just reading through.... :)

Comment: I had to convert it so that I could parent the hair to my armature. But once I did that, it would not show up in the render.

Comment: That is the solution I used in the end, but it still isn't as polished as the particle hair normally is.