# Workflow to get particle animation into 3rd party renderer

Tags: animation, particles, export, alembic

I've built a particle animation I like in blender... basically like dust falling through the air. I want to import this to KeyShot for rendering.

I think I need to convert the particles to mesh, but I want them to still be animated as they are. I think I'm missing a step. I want to be able to export via .abc which KeyShot can import as a Keyframed animation.

I'm pretty new to Blender. If someone can offer me the steps, I'd be very grateful. I assume it'll be something like:

Create Particle Animation > Convert Particles to Mesh > Apply Baked Particle Animation to Mesh (not sure how to do this) > Keyframe animation > Export as Alembic

I haven't been able to get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/convert-cycles-hair-particle-system-to-mesh-object

Comment: You're right. Turns out this script works perfectly. Thanks for the link.