# how to convert hair particles to mesh and keep the geometry of the hair shape?

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

i generated some hair and used the "hair shape" settings to give them some shape. however i want the hair to have subsurface scattering and i heard that hair particles do not support it.

therefore i want to convert my hair to a mesh to apply the material.
but when i click the convert particle in the modifier section all of the hair volume disappears and i am left with long strands.

is there a way to export the hair WITH the "hair shape" settings applied ?

here are the image of the hair i want to convert and what it gives me

[image]

thanks a lot

Comment: from what I read here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/convert-cycles-hair-particle-system-to-mesh-object it looks like you can't directy convert to mesh with thickness, you need convert to mesh, then convert to curve, and give your curve a bevel and a taper to do something that will look like what you currently have, but it may have changed since this time?