# Convert Hair to Mesh while mantaining the shape

Tags: particles, hair, conversion

I've currently got hair I made using the particle system that look something like this:
[image]

and I want to convert these from something that uses a particle system while keeping the looks the same. However, when I use the "convert to mesh" option in the modifiers tab, I get this:
[image]

which has a much larger number of very thin strands showing as lines instead. Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, you need to reconvert to curve and give it a profile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Cycles Hair Particle System to Mesh Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/convert-cycles-hair-particle-system-to-mesh-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hair shape in particle system is not real geometry, you can notice that at  bottom of each hair, they are more like a cards ...

[image]

... if you *Apply* modifier it generates a mesh from hair strands ... you have to *Convert to Curve* ...

[image]

... with *Curve* selected go to *Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel >* **Depth** set some value ... to control thickness of hairs at tips add *Bezier Curve* and use it as **Taper Objectr** under the same panel ...

[image]

... now you can *Convert to Mesh*.

[image]